# Highlight words in markdown content according to search result using Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, search, markdown

I am building React/Django app that is using markdown content I want to put a search bar at which the user can search in the blog content and the words that are matching the search results are highlighted.

I have used react-highlight-words library but I found that It isn't compatible with markdown content so I am trying using react-string-replace library but there is a problem that faced me in the test

react-string-replace returns array not string so I tried to use a hook (useState) which is an empty string and map each word in the array and append it to the hook then put the Hook inside ReactMarkdown element.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown'
import reactStringReplace from 'react-string-replace';
export default function Mark(){
   
   
    const [stringData, setStringData] = React.useState("");
    
    const content = 'Hey my number is 555-555-5555.';
   const replacearray= reactStringReplace(content, 's', (match, i) => (
        `===${match}===`
      ));
console.log(replacearray)
replacearray.map(word =>{
    console.log(word)
    setStringData(stringData + `${word}`)


})
console.log(stringData)
    return(
       <ReactMarkdown>{stringData}</ReactMarkdown>
    )
}
```

The result of `console.log(replacearray)` is:

```
  Array(3) [ "Hey my number i", "===s===", " 555-555-5555." ]
```

The result of `console.log(word)` is:

```
Hey my number i        mark.js:116:13
===s===                mark.js:116:13
 555-555-5555          mark.js:116:13
```

The result of `console.log(stringData)` is:

```
 555-555-5555. 555-555-5555. 555-555-5555. 555-555-5555. 555-555-5555. 555-555-5555. 555-555-5555. 555-555-5555. 555-555-5555. 555-555-5555. 555-555-5555. 555-555-5555. 555-555-5555. 555-555-5555. 555-555-5555. 555-555-5555. 555-555-5555. 555-555-5555. 555-555-5555. 555-555-5555. 555-555-5555. 555-555-5555. 555-555-5555. 555-555-5555. 555-555-5555.
```

so how the result of stringData is like this although the result of each word is the word itself?

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you prepare minimal repro example somewhere. Why reactStringReplace('Hey my number is 555-555-5555', 's'...) result in replacing number 555-555-5555

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the *current* value from the state but the *last* value. This has something to do with how React handles state changes. Here you start with a empty string `""` and you end up with `555-555-555` since that is the last value of the `replacearray`.

The reason you see so many times the `555-555-555` is probably due to caching it will be just `555-555-555` when you do a hard refresh.

```js
export default function Mark() {
  const [stringData, setStringData] = React.useState("");

  replacearray.map((word) => {
    console.log(word);
    setStringData(stringData + `${word}`);
  });
}
```

Instead what you want to use if you set the state inside of a loop is the **callback** function provided by the setState function. This will return the current / most up to date value.

```js
replacearray.map((word) => {
  console.log(word);
  setStringData((prevStringData) => {
    return prevStringData + word;
  });
});
```

Or you could even use the [.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method.

```js
setStringData(replacearray.join(""));
```